# How to use multiple functions in plot3d, with different x and y values

Tags: maple

I know how to use multiple functions. Just put them in square brackets like this

```
plot3d([x + y, 2x + y], x=-3..3, y=-3..3)
```

The thing is - I don't know how to create it, where function will depend on x and y. Like if `x < 0`, it will choose first function. If `x > 0`, it will use second function. I want to use a functions like these:
[image]

Comment: So far I found out about f:=piecewise(...) which allows me to create functions like this. But when I try to implement it to, at least, "implicitplot" function, I just get a fully draw squares, instead of what I need

Comment: I don't understand your notation. Are your last two items (eg. `x=-1.75 {-2.65<=y<=-2}`) meant to denote portions of a plane? Are you just trying to do a 3D plot of portions of cylinder, bounded by planes? I'm sure what you are trying to do is quite possible (and even with smoother bounderies than `implicitplot` or `implicitplot3d` would give), but what you've shown is far from clear as an explanation.